# join 2 lists and create one to many relationship

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to join 2 lists and create one to many relationship?

For example,

```
list 1:
{"High", "Med", "Low"}

list 2:
{"Submitted", "In Progress", "Draft", "Rejected"}
```

final list, I  will have values like this:

```
{
{"High", "Submitted"}, {"High", "In Progress"},{"High", "Draft"}, {"High", "Rejected"},
{"Med", "Submitted"}, {"Med", "In Progress"},{"Med", "Draft"}, {"Med", "Rejected"},
{"Low", "Submitted"}, {"Low", "In Progress"},{"Low", "Draft"}, {"Low", "Rejected"}
}
```

Comment: what gave you tried so far to complete your homework?

Comment: I have tried using .Join and .Concat, but both didn't work. Tried to do .AddRange as well but all of these methods are not working like I'm expecting.

Comment: Unless you don't want imperative code, just run 2 loops and create the Dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can use `Select` and `SelectMany` to create the final List of `KeyVaulePair`.

```
        var list1 = new List<string>() { "High", "Medium", "Low" };
        var list2 = new List<string>() { "Submitted", "In-Progress", "Draft", "Rejected" };
        
        var joined = list1.SelectMany(val1 => list2.Select(val2 => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(val1, val2)));
        foreach(var res in joined) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(res.Key + "," + res.Value);
        }
```

If you want to use imperative style of coding, then just create 2 for loops

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you are looking for a *Cartesian Join*, you can do it with a help of *Linq*:

```
  var list1 = new List<string>() { 
    "High", "Medium", "Low" };

  var list2 = new List<string>() { 
    "Submitted", "In-Progress", "Draft", "Rejected" };
  
  // I've combined values as named tuple: (string first, string second)
  // but you can use anonymous class, or just concat string strings 
  var joined = list1
    .SelectMany(item1 => list2.Select(item2 => (first: item1, second: item2)));
    .ToList();
```

Let's have a look:

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, joined));
```

Outcome:

```
(High, Submitted)
(High, In-Progress)
(High, Draft)
(High, Rejected)
(Medium, Submitted)
(Medium, In-Progress)
(Medium, Draft)
(Medium, Rejected)
(Low, Submitted)
(Low, In-Progress)
(Low, Draft)
(Low, Rejected)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the join method from LINQ:

```
List<(string,string)> joined = list1.Join(list2, x => true, y => true, (x,y) => (x,y)).ToList();
```

The second and third parameter are selectors for list1 and list2. If both are the same, a joined value will be created. If we give the same constant value for both selectors, the joining condition is always fulfilled and hence all possible pairs are created.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JaK6ff

Answer (score 0):

LINQ method syntax for joins is pretty ugly and even counterintuitive, IMHO; query syntax looks much nicer/easier to read:

```
from s in list1
from t in list2
select new { s, t }
```

Or as a tuple:

```
from s in list1
from t in list2
select ( s, t )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do Cartesian product and want to store it in text-value pair then you can use List with SelectListItem. It will give you list with text-value pair.

```
var list1 = new List<string>() { "High", "Medium", "Low" };
var list2 = new List<string>() { "Submitted", "In-Progress", "Draft", "Rejected" };
List<SelectListItem> list3 = new List<SelectListItem>();
   foreach (string str in list1)
   {
      foreach(string str2 in list2)
      {
         list3.Add(new SelectListItem()
         { Text = str, Value = str2 });
      }
   }
```